# Third party library to convert image into pdf and eps format on the fly?

Tags: .net, pdf, eps, on-the-fly

I have an upcoming .NET project that would require conversion from image (bitmap) into .pdf and .eps format. We would prefer to use third party library tool to do this rather than spending the time to reinvent the wheel. Here is the basic requirement:

1. Preferrably a pure .NET library (we might put this converter code in Silverlight application, which won't have access to unmanaged code).
2. Ability to read the input and generate the output on the fly (in memory).

Any recommendation?

Comment: Thanks to the answers guys. After contacting AbcPdf rep, we find it does not support Silverlight at this point. However, we found AbcPdf to fit the bill (we just run the conversion at server side). It supports creating .pdf and different .eps color space well. In addition, it is working on Windows Azure (which is where we're deploying the application).

Answer (score 4):

I've had good luck with Websupergoo's products: http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm

Comment: Thank's Matt. I downloaded abcpdf trial version and made sample apps. It looks promising. I just need to ensure it can work in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 free .Net PDF libraries I have tried in the past (not for image conversion, but they seem to provide that).

- [sharppdf](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net)
- [pdfsharp](http://pdfsharp.com)
- [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 1):

webSupergoo's ABCpdf .NET component can convert bitmap images to PDF and EPS.

You'll need to use either 'AddImageBitmap' or 'AddImageObject' functions, depending on whether you're using indirect or pass-through modes.

Documentation for 'AddImageBitmap' and example code can be found here:
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/addimagebitmap.htm

Indirect and pass-through modes are explained here:
www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/3-concepts/9-images.htm