# Generate single PDF from multiple images

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to create single pdf file from multiple images. For example, I have 12 images then pdf will generate 3 pages with consist of 4 image in single page 2 images in a row.

So, is there any dll, sample I can use to generate pdf from images?[image]

Comment: google for iTextSharp, its very useful, can be used to create pdf's and put images in there

Comment: Have you checked e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273242/third-party-library-to-convert-image-into-pdf-and-eps-format-on-the-fly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I have used table to create 6 images on one page in pdf.

```
Public Function CreatePDF(images As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Byte())) As String
        Dim PDFGeneratePath = Server.MapPath("../images/pdfimages/")
        Dim FileName = "attachmentpdf-" & DateTime.Now.Ticks & ".pdf"

        If images.Count >= 1 Then
            Dim document As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
            Try
                ' Create pdfimages directory in images folder.
                If (Not Directory.Exists(PDFGeneratePath)) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(PDFGeneratePath)
                End If

                ' we create a writer that listens to the document
                ' and directs a PDF-stream to a file
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(PDFGeneratePath & FileName, FileMode.Create))

                ' opens up the document
                document.Open()
                ' Add metadata to the document.  This information is visible when viewing the

                ' Set images in table
                Dim imageTable As New PdfPTable(2)
                imageTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
                imageTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER

                For ImageIndex As Integer = 0 To images.Count - 1
                    If (images(ImageIndex) IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (images(ImageIndex).Length > 0) Then
                        Dim pic As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(SRS.Utility.Utils.ByteArrayToImage(images(ImageIndex)), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

                        ' Setting image resolution
                        If pic.Height > pic.Width Then
                            Dim percentage As Single = 0.0F
                            percentage = 400 / pic.Height
                            pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100)
                        Else
                            Dim percentage As Single = 0.0F
                            percentage = 240 / pic.Width
                            pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100)
                        End If

                        pic.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX
                        pic.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK
                        pic.BorderWidth = 3.0F

                        imageTable.AddCell(pic)
                    End If
                    If ((ImageIndex + 1) Mod 6 = 0) Then
                        document.Add(imageTable)
                        document.NewPage()

                        imageTable = New PdfPTable(2)
                        imageTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
                        imageTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
                    End If
                    If (ImageIndex = (images.Count - 1)) Then
                        imageTable.AddCell(String.Empty)
                        document.Add(imageTable)
                        document.NewPage()
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                ' Close the document object
                ' Clean up
                document.Close()
                document = Nothing
            End Try
        End If

        Return PDFGeneratePath & FileName
    End Function
```

Comment: what is PdfWriter ?

Comment: @Kiquenet it's From itextSharp. Full Name Is "iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter"

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple libraries that have support for this:

1. iTextSharp - [working with images tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images):
2. [pdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net) - [Working with images tutorial](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_an_image_in_original_size_20)
3. [PDF Clown](https://pdfclown.org/)

Comment: yeah, its good example. How can I add 4 images on page..any settings to apply on code.

Comment: You have an example on iTextSharp link I sent you how to add multiple images. If you want them to be displayed differently, just add them on a table instead of paragraph. I didn't try it, but it should work. Or if that is not enough you can merge them in c#. How to merge images in c#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465172/merging-two-images-in-c-net

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the book ["iText in Action"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182617), this more or less also covers iTextSharp, which is a .NET version of the iText PDF library. That is, the C# you must write is almost identical to the Java code samples.

You can download the samples from http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php. A particularly interesting example (code in Java) is the sample on [how to add an image](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=70). The corresponding C# examples can be found on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/).

Good luck!

Comment: Note: itext is commerical or AGPL