# C# Staple multiple documents in printer?

Tags: c#, printing

I am creating an application which will print and staple documents. I can staple multiple pages of one document using the stapling capability of [PrintTicket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket(v=vs.110).aspx) but I want to staple multiple documents together. Any idea?

Comment: Can you not print several logical documents as if they were a single document?

Comment: There isn't any kind of staple functionality within C#. At best, perhaps your printer has an API that allows you to send it a number of jobs and then ask it to staple them, or something like that. Standard printers most likely won't have that kind of functionality.

Also, this question may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012005/c-sharp-stapling-with-lexmark-printer

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I can combine them as one job because these are different file formats.

Comment: Its an HP M4555 printer. Where can i find the printer API for same?

Comment: Perhaps convert them all to a single PDF first? I'm not sure if that will help get it stapled, but it's one way to get it as a single document.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you're using an HP M4555, I can't easily find an API for this printer online, perhaps ask HP technical support?

To be clearer about your goal - you want to access some functionality in your printer, specifically the ability to staple something. This functionality exists on the printer, and not in the language of C#. What you're looking for is the ability to connect to the printer and access its functionality, which is usually done in an API. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if such an API exists already.

Comment: I am able to staple multi pages of single document but i want to staple multiple documents.

Comment: Interesting, how are you able to staple them? Can you post the code?

In any case, then perhaps converting to a single document format (or a document container) would be better - check out some C# PDF libraries, a few sources seem to recommend "iText" - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ea36c5/convert-multiple-text-documents-to-combined-and-individual-p/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686581/generate-single-pdf-from-multiple-images

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure it's possible, but may require some work. You would probably need to write a custom printer driver to interface with the printer's API.

edit-
You are basically at the mercy of the hardware's API. Some tools/options are exposed(collate, duplex printing, etc). Some things may not be exposed. It depends on what the manufacturer decides.

Comment: Its a HP M4555 printer.Where can i find the documentation of print API ?